# How do I get a hold of EventDispatcherChain

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to create a custom `ActionEvent`. When I try to dispatch the event, the `scene.dipatchEvent` is asking me for a `EventDispatcherChain` object. I am not doing anything complex to actually create an implementation of a new `EventDispatcherChain`. How would I get default EventDispatcherChain so I can pass it to `scene.dispatchEvent` ?

**EventType**

```
public class SquirrelEventType extends EventType<SquirrelActionEvent> {

    public SquirrelEventType() {
        super("Squirrel.NotifyPreloader");
    }

}
```

**Event**

```
public class SquirrelActionEvent extends ActionEvent {

private Preloader.PreloaderNotification preloaderNotification;
private String details;
private double progress;

/**
 *
 */
public SquirrelActionEvent(double progress){
    preloaderNotification = new Preloader.ProgressNotification(progress);
}

public PreloaderNotification getPreloaderNotification() {
    return preloaderNotification;
}

public void setPreloaderNotification(PreloaderNotification preloaderNotification) {
    this.preloaderNotification = preloaderNotification;
}
```

Here is the call to `dispatchEvent`

```
SquirrelActionEvent event = new SquirrelActionEvent(0.1d);
mainScene.getEventDispatcher().dispatchEvent(event, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are simply send through Event.fireEvent() which is a static method.